# kendo ui grid edit not firing

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI grid with Inline editing in my website.
Grid is displaying rows. but when i click edit button it does nothing.
it doesn't call any function and fields are not changed as editable.
below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var orderId=$("#OrderId").val();

var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        type: "GET",
        read: {
            url: "/Order/GetOrderItems?OrderId=" + orderId,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        update: {
            url: "/Order/UpdateOrderItemStatus",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "PUT"
        }
    },                
    schema: {            
        model: {
            id: "OrderItemId"               
        }
    }
});
datasource.fetch(function () {
    var data = datasource.at(0);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(datasource);
});


$("#orderItems-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: datasource,        
    columns: [{
        field: "Orderref",
        title: "Order Ref"            
    }, {
        field: "ProductRef",
        title: "Product Ref"
    }, {
        field: "ProductNotes",
        title: "Product Notes"            
    }, {
        field: "OrderStatusId",
        title: "Order Status"           
    },
    { command: "Edit" }],
    editable: "inline"
});
});
```

Comment: `{ command: "edit" }` - case sensitive, use lower case

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it is working..